# Is TestLink dead?

Tags: test-management, testlink

I've been researching test case management tools on and off for about a year pending time to actually work on implementing a solution.
At the end of last year I had chosen TestLink as the solution as it aligned with our existing test reports and the printed output was close enough to be a drop in replacement.

However, it looks like something has happened with TestLink. The Bitnami Docker images are now deprecated as are the AWS images. I had credentials for the TestLink Mantis bug tracker and this no longer works.

Has something happened to TestLink? And if so, what alternatives should I look at for an open source test case management tool?

Comment: I loved Testlink and I'd like to use it again.
However when I installed it on a Linux machine a few weeks ago, it didn't work as it doesn't support the mysqli API, and the old mysql API is not supported anymore by PHP latest version (I am using PHP 8) Tonight I wanted to install it on another box and the web-based installation stops after accepting the license. Very sad. I'd like to participate to the project, but at the moment I have no time for it.

Answer (score 1):

No, TestLink does not appear to be dead. If you check their [GitHub](https://github.com/TestLinkOpenSourceTRMS/testlink-code/tree/testlink_1_9) repository and look at the branches, you will see active development on TestLink 2.0

It's possible the images have been deprecated pending the release of 2.0, but I don't know why your bug tracker credentials would have stopped working. I'd suggest trying a password reset there, and if that fails, a new account.

Comment: I've had a look at those 2.0.0 branches and it looks like nothing has been added for two years for this version (https://github.com/TestLinkOpenSourceTRMS/testlink-code/branches/all)

In addition, from the TestLink website (https://www.testlink.org/) the link to the LinkedIn page doesn't work and the Twitter hasn't been updated in 2 months.

Two months is also the last update seen to the repository. So it feels like something has happened to TestLink within the last two months resulting in the project being killed.

Comment: I'd say it is dead. If you register in their private tracker in mantis there is absolutley no activity. Reported bugs will only receive an answer "Fix it yourself or pay for support (aka donation)". Nothing has moved in the last two years, nothing indicates something is gonna change.